# Run Delphi FMX Form onCreate event code only once and first time

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, oncreate

I have a Delphi application and my main form has an onCreate event with code that I only want to run once and the first time the application is opened on a computer.

So let's say I download the app from Google Play Store or Microsoft Store and run it for the first time, then my onCreate code must run. But if I open the app for a second time then the code must not run again.

What would be the best way to do this? I'm looking for a cross-platform solution that will work on all FMX supported platforms.

(I was thinking of simply creating a hidden text file somewhere and if it doesn't exist then it means the app is opened for the first time and thus run the onCreate code. So any other ideas or ways?)

Comment: This seems very trivial. Just save something on the device to record that the app has been opened, and next time read that value. Why would you think reading a file in the `OnCreate` is not the best solution?

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes. This is what I was saying with the text file. My first thought is to just save a hidden text file somewhere. I'm not sure what you mean by onCreate is not the best solution, because I didn't say anything about that though. I'm definitely using the onCreate event here.

Comment: The easiest solution that can use *exactly* the same code is as you described. The "right" way on Android would be to use SharedPreferences, on iOS would be to use NSUserDefaults, on Windows perhaps the registry

Comment: I meant reading a file in `OnCreate`. Please re-read my comment. Obviously you'd need to save *something* on the device and read it back later.

Comment: I am curious as to what the app will actually do once it has established whether or not it has been run at least once

Comment: @DaveNottage What about MacOS? Would MacOS be the same as on iOS?

Comment: @DaveNottage I'm just testing and experimenting with some random stuff here on my side for possible games/apps that I could make. So it isn't any specific app.

Comment: Quite possibly the same on macOS. Google it :-)

Comment: You could have a look at this component: https://github.com/chrisrolliston/CCR.PrefsIniFile

Answer (score -1):

I've concluded that simply creating a text file on the computer and checking if it exists or not would be the easiest and fastest way to see if the user has opened the app before or not.

Someone in the comments did mention about using SharedPreferences on Android and NSUserDefaults on iOS, but I've decided that text files would be the best for my case.

Comment: Using the platform preferences mechanism is the right way to achieve this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're welcome to give an answer with a cross-platform code solution. I haven't marked my answer as correct yet.